# How to use OpenAPI / Swagger by authenticating endpoints?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

We use swagger in our project and while testing endpoints I need to authenticate in Swagger page (https://localhost:5001/api/index.html). As far as I remember, there was a way to copy the `jwt` of the current session and paste it to request header, etc. But I have not succeeded with this approach. Is there a proper way e.g. using Swagger Inspector as mentioned on [How to Perform a Basic API Test In 3 Steps](https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/how-to-perform-a-basic-api-test/)? Or a smarter way?

Comment: are you asking how to get the token or utilize it after you've gotten it?

Comment: The api page sends requests to teh Controller that requires authentication via `[Authorize]` annotation in .NET Core or MVC. For this reason I encounter authorization error. But If I comment out `[Authorize]` annotation, it works as expected. However, instead of comment out the code, I think I can easily make the api calls as teh user is authenticated via jwt (on another browser tab the application page is opened afetr logged in).

Comment: Are you talking about invoking a request through swaggerUI, with basic auth configured in the request and hit the Service endpoint that needs basic auth to access the resource.